# 2 modelos en una vista razor asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-view-controller

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema cree un modelo para meter dentro otros dos modelos para mostrar sus datos en una sola vista si pongo

```
 public List<Producto> Productos {get; private set;}
 public DetalleEntrega Detalle {get; private set;}
```

Al momento de poner: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>.Producto.campo)` me dice que campo no se encuentro en el contexto y si ya revise que campo si este en mi tabla productos

si lo cambio a sin el list ya no me sale ese error pero si en el

`@foreach(var item in Model.Productos)` me sale error que no es del tipo GetEnumerator.

```
 public Productos {get; private set;}
 public DetalleEntrega Detalle {get; private set;}
```

Los dos modelos dentro de uno

```
public class Mimodelo
{
   public List<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
   public DetalleEntrega Detalle { get; set; }
}
```

El action result en mi controlador Productos

```
public ActionResult Entrega(int id) 
{ 
var Productos = db.Productos.Where(d => e.IdEntrega==id).Include(p => p.Compra).Include(p => p.Empresa); 

var miModelo = new MiModelo();
miModelo.Productos = Productos.ToList();
miModelo.DetallesEntrega = new DetallesEntrega();

return View(miModelo); 
}
```

Vista

```
@model Empresa.Models.Mimodelo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Entrega";
}

<h2>Entrega</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Productos.ProductName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Entrega.Purpose)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Productos.Material)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Entrega.Embarque)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Entrega.Compras)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Productos.Comments)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Entrega.EmpresaT.Empresa)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Productos) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Productos.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Entrega.Purpose)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Productos.Material)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Entrega.Embarque)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Entrega.Compras)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Productos.Comments)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Entrega.EmpresaT.Empresa)
        </td>

        <td>


        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Saludos SenseiLex, como recién andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC te dejo este workshop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY contiene información para quienes están aprendiendo sobre el framework :D

Comment: Tienes un grave problema de entender C# independientemente de MVC. Te sugiero que primero entiendas bien como funciona un `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`campo` no existe porque `campo` no es una propiedad de `List<Producto>` sino de `Producto`

Por la forma de tu modelo significa que `@Model` tiene una lista de productos que necesitarás iterar con un `foreach` por ejemplo para acceder a cada elemento de la lista. Es el `Producto` y no el `List<Producto>` el que tiene el `campo`

Ejemplo. Para este modelo:

```
public class Model
{
   public List<Producto> Productos { get; private set; }
   public DetalleEntrega Detalle { get; private set; }
}
```

Esta estaría en la vista:

```
@foreach(var producto in Model.Productos)
{
    // Acá si debería existir producto.campo
}
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error compañero  getnumerator , usando el  public Productos {get; set;} en el modelo

Comment: Dejalo como antes `List<Producto> { get; private set; }`

Comment: ahora sale error en @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>.Producto.campo) que no lo contiene no se si el foreach va en los dos lados tanto en los <th>, como en los <td> o si no debe usar  los display

Comment: El `foreach` es como cualquier otro `foreach` de C#. Coloca el código completo para poder enconrtar el error. Además debería ser `@Html.DisplayFor(model => producto.campo)`

Comment: Ya puse el codigo completo compañero el error sale en los <th>  no se encuentra en el contexto

Comment: No colocaste las clases `Producto` ni `DetalleEntrega`

Comment: Compañero gracias por tomarte la molestia de explicarme entonces el problema esta en el modo en el que se esta empleando el foreach? y lo de las clases es igual el problema en la vista?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64899/discussion-between-carlos-munoz-and-senseilex).

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `campo` no te aparecera porque la propiedad `Productos` es de tipo `List<T>` y los tipo lista no tienen una propiedad llamada `campo`.

Tendras que incluir en el modelo una propiedad llamada `campo` para que puedas hacer lo que deseas:

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public List<Producto> Productos {get; private set;}
  public DetalleEntrega Detalle {get; private set;}
  public string campo{ get; set;}
}
```

Entonces en la vista:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=> model.campo)
```

Comment: Entonces eso tendria que hacer con todos los campos de las dos entidades compañero?

Comment: Si necesitas utilizar los metodo helpers @Html.DisplayFor si. De lo contrario podrias simplemente crear un input html puro que seria lo mismo: `<input type="text" name="campo" /> `

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al error que te aparece cuando te dice que no es un GetEnumerator es porque en el cshtml donde estas implementando los displayName, al principio del documento tiene que ir `@model IEnumerator<Empresa.Models.Mimodelo>`  y no `@model Empresa.Models.Mimodelo`